# Discord.py bot audio streaming cuts off

Tags: discord.py

When I use the stream command on my bot, it streams about 1min 30s of audio before cutting off and not playing audio, and it doesn't give error messages at the start or when cutting off. When I use the download and play command instead, it plays the whole song without errors or cutoffs.
Stream command:

```
async def play(ctx, *, search):
    voiceChannel=ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await voiceChannel.connect()
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({
        'search_query': search
    })
    htm_content = urllib.request.urlopen(
        'http://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string
    )
    search_results = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", htm_content.read().decode())
    url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + search_results[0]
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
     song_info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song_info["formats"][0]["url"]))
```

Download command:

```
async def download(ctx, *, search):
    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
    except PermissionError:
        await ctx.send("Wait for the current playing music to end or use the 'stop' command")
        return

    voiceChannel=ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await voiceChannel.connect()
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({
        'search_query': search
    })
    htm_content = urllib.request.urlopen(
        'http://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string
    )
    search_results = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", htm_content.read().decode())
    

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download(['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + search_results[0]])
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))
```

Comment: This seems like a youtube problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I found the answer here on stackoverflow dot com at [When playing audio, the last part is cut off. How can this be fixed? (discord.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61959495/when-playing-audio-the-last-part-is-cut-off-how-can-this-be-fixed-discord-py).  I quote, "This is a known issue when you try to make a bot which doesn't download the song it's playing. It is explained here : [https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035010351--Known-Issue-Music-Bots-Not-Playing-Music-From-Certain-Sources"](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035010351--Known-Issue-Music-Bots-Not-Playing-Music-From-Certain-Sources%22)
Turns out you just needed to give FFMPEG options to reconnect and play the song as shown in the code below

```
FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
@client.command(
    name='play',
    description='Streams audio from Youtube. Syntax: w!play [keyword(s)].')
async def play(ctx, *, search):
    voiceChannel=ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await voiceChannel.connect()
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({
        'search_query': search
    })
    htm_content = urllib.request.urlopen(
        'http://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string
    )
    search_results = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", htm_content.read().decode())
    url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + search_results[0]
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
     song_info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song_info["formats"][0]["url"], **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
```

For whatever reason, some